# Inequality between matrix-vector products

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, multivariable-calculus, matrix-equations

$A$ is a full row-rank $m\times n$ matrix with $n > m$. Can I say the following holds for a vector $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$?
$$
\|(AA^\top)^{-1}Ax\| \leq \|A^\top (AA^\top)^{-1} A x\|
$$
If not, under which conditions could this hold?

Answer (score 2):

Recall that $\operatorname{Im}(A^\top)=\ker(A)^{\perp}$. Hence $\operatorname{Im}(A^\top)\oplus \ker(A)= \mathbb{R}^n$.

So every $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$ can be written as $x=A^\top y+z$, where $z\in\ker(A)$ and $y\in\mathbb{R}^m$.

Now $\|(AA^\top)^{-1}Ax\|=\|(AA^\top)^{-1}A(A^ty+z)\|=\|y\|$

Next $\|A^\top (AA^\top)^{-1} A x\|=\|A^\top (AA^\top)^{-1} A(A^\top y+z)\|=\|A^\top y\|$.

Therefore, your question reduces to the following one:

> Does $\|y\|\leq \|A^\top y\|$ hold for every $y\in\mathbb{R}^m$?

This is true if and only if the $m$ singular values of $A^\top$ are greater or equal to 1.

Comment: Thank you!! Is there any way I could even more simply bound $\|(AA^\top)^{-1}A x\|$? I just want to bound this norm fundamentally, I thought bounding it by that projection matrix would be easier but really I just need it to be finite

Comment: @Euler_Salter Hi. The bound will always depend on $\|x\|$. I believe the best you can get is  $\|(AA^\top)^{-1}Ax\|\leq \|(AA^\top)^{-1}\|_{\infty}\|A\|_{\infty}\|x\|$. Notice that $\|A\|_{\infty}$  is the largest singular value of $A$ and  $\|(AA^\top)^{-1}\|_{\infty}$ is the inverse of the square of smallest singular value of $A$.